# Aclaración Join en SQL con PHP

Tags: php, sql, join

Tengo esta consulta para generar una datatable de últimos pagos en una web

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM wp_ac_sesiones LEFT JOIN wp_ac_clientes ON wp_ac_sesiones.id_usuario = wp_ac_clientes.id_usuario";
```

El Join sólo lo necesito para que me muestre el nombre y los apellidos de la persona, después creo las filas

```
<td>'.$row["id"].'</td> 
<td>'.$row["nombre"].'</td>  
<td>'.$row["apellidos"].'</td>  
<td>'.$row["fecha"].'</td>  
<td>'.$row["clases_aumentadas"].'</td>  
<td>'.$row["precio"].'</td>  
<td>'.$row["comentario"].'</td>
```

Pero me coge los datosde wp_ac_clientes y cuando no los tiene,  de wp_ac_sesiones cuando necesito que la id que me muestre sea la del pago, no la del usuario.
No entiendo dónde puede estar el fallo, he probado con diferentes tipos de JOIN pero en todos me pasa lo mismo, de wp_ac_clientes sólo necesito el nombre y apellidos.

Comment: Hola! Te sugiero que especifiques los campos a obtener de las tablas, en la parte del SELECT. Recuerda anteponer el nombre de cada tabla junto a las columnas a mostrar (si es que no optas por los alias, que hacen menos largo el código ;) ). Con eso podrás determinar qué columnas traer, cuáles te sobran, etc. Y usar CASE si quieres que traiga una columna en lugar de otra, según las condiciones que tengas.

Comment: segun la consulta que tienes,  la tabla `wp_ac_sesiones` tiene importancia por eso que si no esta el dato en la tabla cliente, solo te muestre los datos de sesiones solamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes en el select hacer un alias a cada tabla y luego solo traer los campos necesarios y no todos (*) como lo estas haciendo ahora.

```
SELECT clientes.nombre, clientes.apellido, sesiones.id, etc, etc 
FROM wp_ac_sesiones as sesiones 
LEFT JOIN wp_ac_clientes as clientes 
ON wp_ac_sesiones.id_usuario = wp_ac_clientes.id_usuario
```

Comment: Así funciona, pero he tenido que quitar el alias, si no, no había manera